# How does HashSet1.retainAll(HashSet2); work behind the scenes?

Tags: java, hashset

How does `HashSet1.retainAll(HashSet2);` work behind the scenes?

I am adding objects with identical parameters to two different `HashSet`, but when I use the above I don't seem to get the right result. I.e it doesn't detect it's actually the same parameters in the object.

Is this method above comparing the actual address of my objects in the set?

If so, how can I go about making it compare parameters of the objects instead.

Perhaps override equals?

Comment: You need to override the `hashCode` and `equals` methods.

Comment: Thanks @marstran, worked great.

Comment: By the way, you also need to fulfill the contract of the two methods to make it work as expected. If two objects are equal, they must also have the same hash code. However, if two objects have the same hash code, they may not be equal (due to hash collisions).

Answer (score 0):

I have overwritten the hashCode and .equals methods in my class and this has resulted in the method comparing the correct parameter's rather than object address's. Thanks goes to @marstran for his advice on this matter.